# Could someone explain the proof of this formula clearly? I got the wrong values for spanning trees with this formula and with Cayley's formula

Tags: graph-theory, spanning-tree

The passage quoted below is from "The number of spanning trees of a graph" by Jianxi Li, Wai Chee Shiu, and An Chang, Applied Mathematics Letters 23.3 (2010): 286-290, DOI:[10.1016/j.aml.2009.10.006](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.aml.2009.10.006), [MR2565192](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2565192), [Zbl 1227.05125](https://zbmath.org/1227.05125).

Could someone clearly explain the proof of the inequality on the number of spanning trees of a graph $G$ in this passage?

This inequality seems to contradict Cayley's formula for the number of spanning trees of the complete graph. I tested a complete graph $G=K_5$. This formula gave me $121$ as an upper bound for the number of spanning trees while Cayley's gave me $125$. I am not able to  figure out how it went wrong.

[image]
[image]

Could someone provide some insights?

Comment: I agree with you that the formula in the theorem gives $4 \cdot ( (2\cdot 10 - 4 - 1 - 4)/2)^2 = 121$ for $G=K_5$, which cannot be correct since $K_5$ has $125$ spanning trees. I did not look at the proof at all to see what goes wrong (or what assumptions are tacitly made).

Comment: There should be something that's wrong in the derivation.

Comment: This is from Li, Jianxi, Wai Chee Shiu, and An Chang. ”The number of spanning trees of a graph.” Applied Mathematics Letters 23.3 (2010): 286-290.

Comment: There is something that's gone wrong in the derivation. Maybe from the arithmetic mean-geometric mean inequality step itself. But I am not able to figure out where. The authors seem to be quite reputed therefore I cannot reach a conclusion.

Comment: Update: the formula failed for complete graphs for all the tested n values. But all other mentioned graphs  succeeded with the different values of n. Therefore the formula is partially correct and might need adjustments.

Answer (score 15):

The problem is that for a complete graph, $\mu_{n-1} \leq \delta$ is wrong, and thus $f(\delta) < f(\mu_{n+1})$. This can be fixed by adding a special case for the complete graph (for other graphs $\mu_{n-1}\leq\delta$ because the algebraic connectivity is at most the vertex connectivity).

Comment: What kind of special cases could be considered here?

Comment: @NoxiousReptile: Command Master is saying the *only* graphs for which the theorem as stated is false are the complete graphs.